# Multiplexer in vhdl with structural design

Tags: vhdl, hardware, hdl, xilinx-ise, hardware-design

I am totally new to VHDL and I want to implement
the following **MUX** for a logical **implication** S0 => S1 
without using other gates.

[image: 4-1 MUX]

I want to use **structural design**, but one of my main problems is that I don't understand how to
map the ports correctly so that I am implementing the given implication.

My code so far is compiling and iSim starts but I get two warnings:

1. mux41_impl remains a black-box sinse it has no binding entity.
2. mux_out_test has value U

Furthermore, I understand that my component has to match the entity exactly
but if I rename it to the entities name I am getting an illegal recurion message.

**code**

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity MUX41_IMPL_top is
port (
    D0, D1, D2, D3, S0, S1: in STD_LOGIC;
    mux_out : out STD_LOGIC
);
end MUX41_IMPL_top;

architecture structure of MUX41_IMPL_top is

component MUX41_IMPL
    port (
        D0, D1, D2, D3, S0, S1: in STD_LOGIC;
        mux_out : out STD_LOGIC
    );
end component;

begin

u1: MUX41_IMPL port map (D0, D1, D2, D3, S0, S1, mux_out);
end structure;
```

**testbench code**

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity MUX41_IMPL_SIMBOX is
end MUX41_IMPL_SIMBOX;

architecture TEST_MUX41_IMPL of MUX41_IMPL_SIMBOX is

component MUX41_IMPL is
    port (
        D0, D1, D2, D3, S0, S1: in STD_LOGIC;
        mux_out : out STD_LOGIC
    );
end component;

signal D0_test : STD_LOGIC := '1';
signal D1_test : STD_LOGIC := '0';
signal D2_test : STD_LOGIC := '1';
signal D3_test : STD_LOGIC := '1';
signal S0_test, S1_test : STD_LOGIC := '0';
signal mux_out_test : STD_LOGIC;

for my_MUX41_IMPL : MUX41_IMPL use entity work.MUX41_IMPL_top(structure);

begin
    my_MUX41_IMPL : MUX41_IMPL
    port map (
    D0 => D0_test,
    D1 => D1_test,
    D2 => D2_test,
    D3 => D3_test,
    S0 => S0_test,
    S1 => S1_test,
    mux_out => mux_out_test
    );

    S0_test <= not S0_test after 2 ns;
    S1_test <= not S1_test after 4 ns;

end TEST_MUX41_IMPL;
```

Comment: WARNING:HDLCompiler:<line number in design file for MUX41_IMPL_SIMBOX> - "mux41_impl" remains a black-box since it has no binding entity. It's a warning because components are not required to be bound. Where is the entity and architecture for MUX41_IMPL? Without those found in a reference library (which can be work) the instance won't be bound. Why is MUX41_IMPL_top shown here? It's not used.

Comment: Where is `MUX41_IMPL` defined?  When you say _I want to implement the following MUX_ do you perhaps mean to say _I want to __use__ the following MUX_?

Comment: @rtx13 in the code section, not the textbench there is the `MUX41_IMPL_top` entity. This is my 4:1 MUX entity.

@user1155120
I renamed this to MUX41_IMPL_top because i got a recursion if it is named like the component itself.

Comment: @rtx13 and yes I want to use this MUX to implement the logical implication "S0 => S1". just by using structural design :)

Comment: I'm still not sure I follow.  `MUX41_IMPL_SIMBOX(TEST_MUX41_IMPL)` uses `MUX41_IMPL_top(structure)`.  In turn, `MUX41_IMPL_top(structure)` uses `MUX41_IMPL`.  Where is `MUX41_IMPL` defined?  In other words, where is the (non-structural) RTL for `MUX41_IMPL`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
entity MUX41_IMPL_top is
port (
    D0, D1, D2, D3: in STD_LOGIC;
    Sel : in std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);    
    mux_out : out STD_LOGIC

);
end MUX41_IMPL_top;

architecture structure of MUX41_IMPL_top is
begin

with Sel select
    mux_out <=  D0 when "00",
                D1 when "01",
                D2 when "10",            
                D3 when "11",            
                '0' when others;    

architecture structure;
```